# How to increase the output electricy of a usb port by using two

Tags: voltage, usb

Would there be a way to some way combine two 5v 1a usb ports to get 10v 1a or would i get 5v 2a?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't "combine" two USB port in series, USB ports have usually common ground.

Although the common limit of a USB port is 500 - 900 mA, but yes, with proper wiring you might be lucky to get 2 A out of this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you're counting as a USB port.

If you've got some power banks you could wire them in series and get your 10V/1A.  Otherwise, no, as they have a common ground.  Try to wire them in series and hopefully the USB's current limiter trips before you burn it out.